# Using OpenID on a PhoneGap platform

Tags: javascript, openid, cordova, iphone-web-app

I am currently developing an application using PhoneGap. My application used OpenID to authenticate a user. After successfully authenticate a user, it should be return back to my application. I have used location.href to redirect the page to a local address (something like file:///var/applications/.../index.html for iOS app). However, it seems that PhoneGap cannot redirect a local page from remote site. Only a white screen was displayed. Is there any way for me to return back to my application after authentication?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Terris, I was wondering if you used a library for your OpenID access, and if so which one? If you did, did you have any problems building it to PhoneGap? Martin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use the childbrowser plugin for that.
Also you may be able to ajax call the openid login stuff using a webpage on your own server?